Is there a fast way to verify if a wallet is the correct one?
I recently read about a sneaky trick some hackers are using to steal money. They use a malicious software that can mess with your copy-paste when you’re dealing with wallet addresses. You copy an address, but when you paste it, it changes to a different one that looks almost the same — same start, same end - just a few different characters in the middle. And because of that, you end up sending your funds to the wrong place without even noticing.
It’s super easy to miss, especially if you’re busy and just trying to get stuff done quickly.

Is there a fast way to verify if a wallet is the correct one before doing a transaction (even with a copy/paste)?
Also, why don't exchanges implement better security measures?
Thanks.


Question 1:
Address spoofing and clipboard hijacking are a real threat (source).
The safest way would be to check each character and make sure they are the same. You can also initiate a transaction with a small amount and check on the blockchain if the wallet received it.
Another way would be to use a simple tool I created after a friend lost some of his funds.
The tool is called "Wallet Inspector". You can use it on the web or on iOS. It generates a unique 6-digit security code for wallet addresses, providing a quick way to verify address integrity.
If the codes match, you can be confident that the address hasn't been tampered with.
Question 2:
As for why exchanges don't implement better security measures, it's a complex issue. Many exchanges already have various security features in place, but they often have to balance security with user convenience.
That said, some exchanges are implementing features like address whitelisting and mandatory waiting periods for new addresses.
